# Same page looks great in Firefox & crome But Not in IE8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, javascript, jquery

I have a site hosted at: http://41.223.52.100/ which i used jbar to display certain text on the page.

The same page looks great in Firefox & google crome but not in IE8, Can't figure-out why!
 Please share your kind inputs, on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position should be *absolute* in the message id tag, not *fixed*. As for the rounded corners, it is currently not supported in IE.